# PHP Unzip function creating hidden system files

Tags: php, wordpress, zip, unzip

I have the below code (part of a function) that i run on my wordpress site.
It works fine, but it also creates a system file (starting with a '.') for each file.
This wouldn't normally be a problem but my HTML5 audio player picks these files up, and obviously can't play them so it looks like the player is broken.

Is there a way to stop the creation of these files from the Zip side of it? Or am i going to have to stop it from the player side?

I would rather stop them being created at all, as they take up space.

The code is:

```
   // Unzip files to temp unzip folder, ignoring anything that is not a .mp3 extension
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $filename = $zip_file_path;

   if ($zip->open($filename)!==TRUE) {
      exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
   }

   for ($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles;$i++) {
      $info = $zip->statIndex($i);
      $file = pathinfo($info['name']);
      if(strtolower($file['extension']) == "mp3") {
           file_put_contents($temp_unzip_path.'/'.basename($info['name']), $zip->getFromIndex($i));
      } else {
      $zip->deleteIndex($i);
      }
   }
   $zip->close();
```

Comment: What are the filenames? Are they .DS_Store files? What are you using to create the zip?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add to your mp3 condition by checking that the first character of the filename is not a period?

```
      if(strtolower($file['extension']) == "mp3" && $info['name'][0] != '.') {
```

Comment: The system files are not already in the Zip file... they are being created by the unzip process - i believe they are unix system files.
I suppose i could just add a few lines within my overall PHP function that deletes these files after the unzip, but was wondering if there was a better way to do it.